# Get user input with arguments in Python

Tags: python, command-line-interface

TL;DR I need to get a user input that contains an argument in order to do something, I need my own script that gets user input, and acts like it's its own interpreter.

My goal is to make my own CLI with my own commands.
What I need now is to get user input within a python script. The grammar for my CLI is below: (The thing I don't know how to do)

```
COMMAND + ARGUMENT1 + ARGUMENT2 + ARGUMENT3
```

Example of what I want to do:

```
say "hi this is a test"
hi this is a test
```

I have a plan for how I can make the commands with arguments,
I make a folder named 'bin' and I put python scripts in them.
Inside the python scripts are functions.
Depending on the command type, either I call the functions do do something, or it prints a output.

But for now, I need to know HOW to get user input with ARGUMENTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in `argparse` module as @ToTheMax said can create complex command line interfaces.

By default `argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args()` will read the command line arguments to your utility from `sys.argv`, but if you pass in an array, it will use it instead.

You can lex (split into an array of "words") a string just like the shell is using `shlex.split()` which is also built in. If you use quotation marks like in your example, the words between them won't be split apart, just as in the shell.

Here's a complete example. Refer to the documentation, because this is a bit of an advance usage of `argparse`. There is a section that talks about "subcommands" which is what this example is based on.

```py
import argparse
import shlex

def do_say(args):
    print(args.what)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
say_command = subparsers.add_parser('say')
say_command.add_argument('what')
say_command.set_defaults(func=do_say)

command = 'say "hi this is a test"'

args = parser.parse_args(shlex.split(command))
args.func(args)
```

The `cmd` module is another built-in way to make a command prompt, but it doesn't do the parsing for you, so you'd maybe combine it with `argparse` and `shlex`.

Answer (score 1):

I realize I already have a question that is answered.

You can find it here:
[How do you have an input statement with multiple arguments that are stored into a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60365468/how-do-you-have-an-input-statement-with-multiple-arguments-that-are-stored-into)

Here is the correct code:

```
def command_split(text:str) -> (str,str):
    """Split a string in a command and any optional arugments"""
    text = text.strip() # basic sanitize input
    space = text.find(' ')
    if space > 0:
        return text[:space],text[space+1:]
    return text,None

x = input(":>")
command,args = command_split(x)
# print (f'command: "{command:}", args: "{args}"')

if command == 'echo':
    if args == None:
        raise SyntaxError
    print (args)
```

A more simple way:

```
x = input(":>")
if x.split(" ")[0] == 'echo':
    echoreturn = ' '.join(x.split(" ")[1:])
    print(echoreturn)
```

My version to @rgov 's post: (Thank you!)

```
import argparse
import shlex

def do_say(args):
    print(args.what)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
say_command = subparsers.add_parser('say')
say_command.add_argument('what')
say_command.set_defaults(func=do_say)

while True:
    try:

        command = input(":>")

        args = parser.parse_args(shlex.split(command))
        args.func(args)
    except SyntaxError:
        print("Syntax Error")
    except ValueError:
        print("Value Error")
    except:
        print("")
```